# python lxml.html: returns null list for yahoo finance

Tags: python, lxml

The following code returns an empty list;

```
import lxml.html
url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=AYR+Profile'
content = lxml.html.parse(url)
sector = content.xpath('//*[@id="yfncsumtab"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a')
print sector
[]
```

I cross checked on the console in chrome ..

```
$x('//*[@id="yfncsumtab"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a')[0].text
```

and I get the output as;

```
'Services'
```

Where am I messing up?

Comment: I don't know if this will fix it, but in your console command you have ``tr[3]/td[2]/a`` at the end, and in your code you have ``tr[2]/td[2]/a``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `html` code resolved by `lxml` there aren't `<tbody>` elements, so you have to omit them in the `xpath` expression. Also, add `text()` at the end to extract the content of the link:

```
sector = content.xpath('//*[@id="yfncsumtab"]/tr[2]/td[1]/table[2]/tr/td/table/tr[2]/td[2]/a/text()')
```